# Creation order of controllers

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to create an `Ember.Route`, and I need the corresponding template to know the current route's path. I know there's `ApplicationController.currentPath` for that, but it my route's `setupController()` I can get the `ApplicationController`, but if I get the `currentPath` property it returns `undefined`.

Why is it so?

This is my code (simplified to show just the problem):

```js
AxpoEM = Ember.Application.create({});

AxpoEM.Router.map(function() {
    this.route('something', { path: '/'})
});

AxpoEM.SomethingRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        var path = this.controllerFor('application').get('currentPath');
        controller.set('path', path);
    }
});
```

And this is the HTML:

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="something">
  Path: {{path}}    
</script>
```

Here is a (non-)working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Nxq6K/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. There's no need to access the `ApplicationController`, there's a `routeName` property in each Route:

```js
AxpoEM.SomethingRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        var path = this.get('routeName');
        controller.set('path', path);
    }
});
```

Fixed fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Nxq6K/3/

Answer (score 1):

I get this working injecting the `ApplicationController`, in the `SomethingController` using the `needs`

```
AxpoEM.SomethingController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    needs: ['application'],
    path: function() {        
        return this.get('controllers.application.currentPath');
    }.property('controllers.application.currentPath')
});
```

The updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/bDUyN/

Comment: I don't have direct access to the SomethingController. The problematic code is in a ParentRoute which my real Routes inherit from, so there's no automatically created ParentController to do what you suggest. Therefore, the code should live in ParentRoute (I guess).